# Using multiple PDO prepared statements at once

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is a request for confirmation/clarification based on a *very* easily missed comment from 6 years ago in the PHP.net manual for PDO::prepare, which I haven't seen discussed elsewhere (even in the great phpdelusions blog). It's such a powerful possibility if it's true that I feel it deserves a little wider coverage and search highlighting for others (or needs debunking if not).

Here's the comment (by Hayley Watson):

> It is possible to prepare in advance several statements against a single connection.
>   As long as that connection remains open the statements can be executed and fetched from
>   as often as you like in any order; their "prepare-execute-fetch" steps can be interleaved
>   in whichever way is best.
>
> So if you're likely to be using several statements often (perhaps within a loop of
>   transactions), you may like to consider preparing all the statements you'll be using up front.

I have some code that must run like (pseudocode):

```
foreach (fetchAll row with PDO) {
    process row results
    if (condition)
        update table with processed results
    else
        delete row no longer needed
}
```

According to that comment, I could create TWO prepared statements BEFORE the loop, one for the update query and one for the delete query, then execute (only) within the loop. As long as the handles are different and preserved, the connection should cache both, I can use them interchangeably and I'd not have to do any SQL statement parsing INSIDE the loop, which would be very inefficient:

```
// do statement prepare/execute/fetchAll for main loop, then...
$update_stmt = $PDO->prepare($update_query);
$delete_stmt = $PDO->prepare($delete_query);
foreach (fetchAll row) {
    process row results
    if (condition)
        $update_stmt->execute(some_processed_values);
    else
        $delete_stmt->execute(some_other_values);
}
```

Since most questions here only discuss using one prepared statement at a time, and this has excellent implications for code efficiency if widely applied, would anyone like to confirm that this is definitely the case (at least from PHP7)? If so, I guess other neat applications for this form of code could be shared in the solutions.

Comment: Yes, using a prepared statement upfront outside of the loop will give you performance benefits as MySql would cache it https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/statement-caching.html

Comment: I can confirm this is how prepared statements are meant to be used. Don't see the problem. There's no restrictions mentionned on php.net or on any other docs

Comment: That's just one of the many benefits of using prepared statements.

Comment: Have you simply tried checking that out?

Comment: Would be nice if you can check for performance I didnt see much difference even separeted statements are faster than others..

Comment: Thanks for your confirmations. No, it's not a problem. Just because there is no mention of a restriction in the manual does not necessarily mean that it's _possible_. (There are lots of other omissions in the PHP.net documentation for PDO.) It seemed odd that the only mention of this useful behaviour was in a comment, and I've not seen code examples explicitly showing this elsewhere. So it's not immediately obvious, and I thought new coders using PDO (like me) might find this confirmation useful and instructive. ;)

Answer (score 5):

There's no problem with using multiple prepared statements at the same time and executing them out of order.

You can run code such as the following with intertwined statements and it will work.

```
$stmt1 = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO addplate(Plate) VALUES(?)');
$stmt2 = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE addplate SET Plate=? WHERE Plate=?');

$stmt1->execute(['val1']);
$stmt2->execute(['val2', 'val1']);
$stmt1->execute(['val1']);
$stmt2->execute(['val2', 'val1']);
$stmt1->execute(['val1']);
```

This can bring you some performance benefit when for some reason you can't avoid N+1 problem. You prepare the inner query once and then execute it inside the loop multiple times.

However, this could be a problem with result-producing queries if you want to run [unbuffered query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php) (it's very rarely used). PDO by default executes buffered queries, so you need to switch them off to run into this issue.

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);

$stmt1 = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM addplate WHERE Plate=?');
$stmt2 = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM addplate WHERE Plate=?');

$stmt1->execute(['val1']);
var_dump($stmt1->fetch());
$stmt2->execute(['val2']); // <-- Error if stmt1 still has more records
var_dump($stmt2->fetch());
```

It will produce:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.

Comment: Upvoted, but I'd add that unbuffered queries only matters for `SELECT` or other statements that return a result set (for example, `SHOW`, `CALL`, `DESCRIBE`). Statements like `UPDATE` or `DELETE` have no result set, so there is nothing to buffer.

Comment: Thanks for this, and especially the comment about setting buffered vs. unbuffered attributes. It's clear buffered is essential for this pre-preparing of multiple statements in a loop. But I've seen conflicting comments about whether that attribute setting actually works in runtime (per PDO query) or is only effective on the connection creation. It would be preferable for my code to use both, since unbuffered may play nicer with some of my fetch loops. Is there a definitive answer on newer PHP 7/MySQL?

Comment: Just forget about unbuffered queries. You don't need them. They're more trouble than they worth.

Answer (score 1):

Nice Question! First statement ?

```
    $id = '2';
    $username = 'John';
    if ($id === 2){
        $array = array(':username'=> $username, ':id'=>$id);
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET username = ? WHERE id = ?";
    }else{
        $array = array(':id'=>$id);
        $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = ?";
    }

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($array);
```

Second statement :

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET username = ? WHERE id = ?";
$sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = ?";
$stmt1 = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt2 = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    if ($id === 2){
        $array = array(':username'=> $username, ':id'=>$id);
        $stmt1->execute($array);
    }else{
        $array = array(':id'=>$id);
        $stmt2->execute($array);
    }
```

Simple statements:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET username = ? WHERE id = ?")->execute([':username'=> $username, ':id'=>$id]);
$stmt = null;

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM users WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->execute([':id'=>$id]);
$stmt = null;
```

First statement run 1 second faster than second statement.

Runing separete statements at the bottom, both update and delete at same time much faster than others.

is that because of if statements ?

I am runing php 7.4.0 and mysql 8.0

Updated if someone wants to try.